# How to create test-only routes and views on playframework 2?

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am developing a Play! 2 application that generates some html/js widgets which will be embedded into 3rd-party websites. Their linking are dynamic thus I cannot have static test files.

How can I have test views(and routes to those views) that works only in test mode, so I can test with Selenium.

Basically I want to add testView1.scala.html, testView1.scala.html to test/views and have routes to that, but do not want that these work in production mode. What is a good approach to that?

Answer (score 3):

i'm not sure if this is the best way, but here is how i would do it.

1. create the test route and route to a test controller
2. in the test controller, create a wrapped action and have all of your routes use this action
3. this wrapped action will test to see what mode play is in. if play isnt in test mode, forward to 404, otherwise, run the action

when i get home, ill add some code to support, but this is the general workflow i would use.

hope it helps.

Comment: No code needed. I already implemented exactly the way you described. I am looking for a better alternative. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Simples...(now with years to answer..). A bit similar to what @mbseid answered:

Rename your */conf/routes* to */conf/prod.routes*, and specify it in your */conf/application.conf*:

```
play.http.router = prod.Routes
```

Create a test routes file, e.g. */conf/test.routes*, that exposes the test only route and delegates the rest to the prod routes.

```
 /test/only/something    controllers.testonly.TestOnlySomethingController.someMethod()  
 -> /                    prod.Routes
```

Make sure your test only controllers are in a different package than other controllers.

When you start your test application override *play.http.router*, e.g.:

```
 sbt run -Dplay.http.router=test.Routes
```

It is a useful pattern in microservices environments with integration tests to expose data not otherwise exposed.

Note, **play.http.router** used to be called **application.router** before v2.5+